# conditional on value greater than

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I write a conditional jquery statement saying value greater than?

This is what I have but i don't think it is correct:

```
} else if ($('.store_checkbox:checked').val > 63){
    $("#hidden_taxon_message").show();
```

the .val > 63 is what I am having a problem with

Comment: `val` is a function. Use `val()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
} else if ($('.store_checkbox:checked').val() > 63){
    $("#hidden_taxon_message").show();
```

**[val](http://api.jquery.com/val/)** is a function in JQuery so you have to use ().

Answer (score 1):

The [**jQuery method**](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is `.val()` you forgot `()`

Try this:

```
$('.store_checkbox:checked').val() > 63
```

Answer (score 1):

You have forgot `()` after `val` and insert the value inside `parseInt` to tell to javascrip that is a number not a string

try this:

```
} else if (parseInt($('.store_checkbox:checked').val()) > 63){
    $("#hidden_taxon_message").show();
```